# cannot get value from textbox inside table div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get textbox value which i have assign class="qty-text". It can be multiple textboxes but for simplicity of my example i have used only one here. Tried below code but it is returning undefined value. Please help to sort out this issue.

```js
$(document).on('click','.qButton',function(e){

var id="a318d5";
var get_value = $('#a318d5').closest("div.quantity").find("input[class='qty-text']").val();
alert(get_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
 
        <td class="action"><a href="#" id="a318d5" class="remove_cart"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                                    <td class="cart_product_img">
                <a href="#">Image</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="cart_product_desc">
                                        <h5>Product</h5>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span> M  </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="price"><span>$320</span></td>
                                    <td class="qty">
                                        <div class="quantity">
                                            <input type="number" class="qty-text" step="1" min="1" max="1" name="quantity" value=3>
                                        </div>
                                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down downarr"></i>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="total_price"><span>960</span></td>
                                </tr>
</table>

<button class="col-xs-12 qButton">select</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with DOM hierarchy in you code. `input.qty-text` is somewhere inside another `td` in the current `tr` (we can not even know exactly, the next `td` or not). So, try this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.qButton', function(e) {
  var id="a318d5";
  var get_value = $('#' + id).closest("tr").find("input.qty-text").val();

  alert(get_value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Child Selector (“parent > child”)**

```js
$(document).on('click','.qButton',function(e){
  //  input[name='Author["+sumClick+"][firstName]']
var id="a318d5";
var get_value = $("quantity > .qty-text ").val();
alert(get_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
 
        <td class="action"><a href="#" id="a318d5" class="remove_cart"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                                    <td class="cart_product_img">
                <a href="#">Image</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="cart_product_desc">
                                        <h5>Product</h5>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span> M  </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="price"><span>$320</span></td>
                                    <td class="qty">
                                        <div class="quantity">
                                            <input type="number" class="qty-text" step="1" min="1" max="1" name="quantity" value=3>
                                        </div>
                                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down downarr"></i>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="total_price"><span>960</span></td>
                                </tr>
</table>

<button class="col-xs-12 qButton">select</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```js
$(document).on('click','.qButton',function(e){

var id="a318d5";
var get_value = $('#a318d5').parents('tr').find("input[class='qty-text']").val();  
alert(get_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
 
        <td class="action"><a href="#" id="a318d5" class="remove_cart"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                                    <td class="cart_product_img">
                <a href="#">Image</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="cart_product_desc">
                                        <h5>Product</h5>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span> M  </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="price"><span>$320</span></td>
                                    <td class="qty">
                                        <div class="quantity">
                                            <input type="number" class="qty-text" step="1" min="1" max="1" name="quantity" value=3>
                                        </div>
                                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down downarr"></i>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="total_price"><span>960</span></td>
                                </tr>
</table>

<button class="col-xs-12 qButton">select</button>
```